# Obtaining a valid access token for Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, access-token, microsoft-graph-api

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC5 Web App that uses Azure ADAL libraries to authenticate users, it works fine, however, when I manually send requests to graph, ex: GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me or GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=from/displayName eq 'whatever'.

I have tried updating the App Registration in Azure as to add the required Graph permissions, and I have also tried creating new app registrations, no matter what I do my requests will always respond 401 Unauthorized, is there anything I am missing?

EDIT: Example response from Postman

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "Access token validation failure.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "a142576b-acce-4e59-8a8d-adede61aaf59",
      "date": "2017-04-05T13:27:36"
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT: C# Request Example

```
public async Task<GroupGraph> GetGroupIdByDisplayName(string displayName)
{
    var accessToken = await authenticationService.GetTokenUserOnly();
    GroupGraph groupGraphResponse = null;
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=from/displayName eq '{displayName}'"))
            {
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
                using (var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result)
                {
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        using (var content = response.Content)
                        {
                            var result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            groupGraphResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GroupGraph>(result);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return groupGraphResponse;
    }
```

EDIT: The way I obtain the token

```
public async Task<string> GetTokenUserOnly()
    {
        string signedInUserID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
        string tenantID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
        string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;

        // get a token for the Graph without triggering any user interaction (from the cache, via multi-resource refresh token, etc)
        ClientCredential clientcred = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
        // initialize AuthenticationContext with the token cache of the currently signed in user, as kept in the app's database
        AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(aadInstance + tenantID, new TableTokenCache(signedInUserID));
        //AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(graphResourceID, clientcred, new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));
        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(graphResourceID, clientcred);
        return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please describe what you mean by `when I manually send requests to graph`? Are you sending the requests through a tool like Postman or Fiddler? Have you included `Authorization` header in your requests?

Comment: Yes, I have included Authorization header in my requests, I have tried using both Postman and C# to send my requests.

Comment: Please update your question and include the code. Also you should see details about 401 error. Please include them in your question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use ADAL to get tokens for graph.*microsoft*.com. ADAL is for graph.*windows*.net.

In order to get tokens for the Graph library (graph.windows.com) look into the Nuget Package Microsoft.Graph. Microsoft also has some [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/get-started/aspnetmvc) on how to pull user info using Graph.

Be forewarned though, using Graph Libraries and ADAL libraries side by side can lead to some weird side effects, such as the credential cache being cleared.

Comment: This is not accurate. You can absolutely use ADAL to get a token to the Microsoft Graph (`https://graph.microsoft.com`). You just need to make sure you are using a V1 application and following the V1 protocol/endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using the client credential grant flow to acquire the access token for graph api(`graphResourceID` is `https://graph.microsoft.com` ?) :

```
  AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(graphResourceID, clientcred);
```

So you need to grant app permission in azure ad portal :

[image]

For error "Access token validation failure" , you could use online tool like http://jwt.calebb.net/ to decode your access token , check the audience or lifetime of the access token .

Comment: Those permissions are already in the app registration, and yes graphResourceID is https://graph.microsoft.com

Answer (score 0):

To obtain a valid token for Microsoft Graph API you can use `Azure.Identity`.

To use any implementation of `TokenCredential` we need to build our own `IAuthenticationProvider`.

```
public class TokenCredentialAuthenticationProvider : IAuthenticationProvider
{
    private readonly TokenCredential _tokenCredential;

    public TokenCredentialAuthenticationProvider(TokenCredential tokenCredential)
    {
        _tokenCredential = tokenCredential;
    }
    public async Task AuthenticateRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var accessToken = await _tokenCredential.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com" }), CancellationToken.None);
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken.Token);
    }
}
```

Now we can for instance use AzureCliCredential to acquire an access token.

Open Powershell and type in `az login` in order to login with your Azure AD account.

In Azure you could also use `Managed Identity` to get a token based on a Azure resource e.g. Azure App Service. Here need to use `ManagedIdentityToken`.

Usage:

```
var client = new GraphServiceClient(new TokenCredentialAuthenticationProvider(new AzureCliCredential()));
var user = await client.Me.Request().GetAsync();
```