# How to consume Graph API with a ADAL token?

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory

in my Xamarin.forms project, I use ADAL (Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory) to authenticate on the Azure portal (Auth 1.0 endpoint). That part work great, but I need to get the security group of the user. So I use this code and passing the token received with ADAL:

```
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
 HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf");
 message.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
 HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(message);
 string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

I always got StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized'.
In my azure AD app registration, I add the Graph API and these permissions:
[image]
[image]

I think I miss something. Any idea?

----- EDIT 1 ---
Here my payload. I changed it for a picture for lisibility. I don't know how to post json here
[image]

**----- EDIT 2 ---**
OH! I see. I think I need to understand more the Azure Login process. For now I follow an example of ADAL and Azure that let my log and use some function in my backend. So the login process use:

```
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority); var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, uri, platformParams);
```

Where authority =  https://login.microsoftonline.com/mysite.com, ResourceID is my backend app ID and clientID is my native app ID. So Shawn is correct, I do not use the Graph.microsoft.com to get the token. Do we have another way to achieve all that? The need of using Graph is only to get the AD group the user has to adjust permission inside the app.

Comment: I think I found the reason. The user I use for testing already accept the consent. Now that I add the new graph permission, I need to force it to re-accept the new consent but I can find a way to force it. I try with platformParams.PromptBehavior = PromptBehavior.Auto; without success.

Comment: Pierre, what are you asking in your update? Simply update your code to request a token to Graph rather than whatever you have set for `resource`. You might want to open a new question as you are asking something completely different than before.

Comment: Shawn, I was not aware that I can call 2 times in a row the AcquireTokenAsync. Once with my backend ID and get a token with aud starting with 93f, and the second call with the Graph URL to get a second token valid for the graph. Now all is working. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in your comment. If you add a new permission to your application, you must ask the user to re-consent to the app.

You can force re-consent through ADAL by setting the `PromptBehavior` to `Always`:

```
platformParams.PromptBehavior = PromptBehavior.Always
```

Or you can simply modify your Login URL to force it, by adding the query string:

```
&prompt=consent
```

In terms of building an app to help overcome this problem, if you think your app will be changing permissions after release, you can integrate logic which detects `Unauthorized`, and then sends the user to re-consent.

Another option is for your app to track changes which may require a new consent prompt, and detect when the user uses this new version of your application the first time, and asks them to consent.

In our new App Model V2, we support the concept of [Incremental and Dynamic Consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-compare#incremental-and-dynamic-consent), which should get rid of this problem all together for you.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I try with the PromptBehavior.Always but nothing change. The login view do not ask for more consent. So I decide to delete de native app in the Azure Portal then recreate it. Now I got the "new" consent but I always got unauthorized when I ask for https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf. Do you think I need more permission for that?

Comment: You can [use documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_list_memberof) to answer that question.

Comment: Yes I aleready read that. He said that for MemberOf I only need Graph->Read all groups. I set that permission to my native app, then execure et accept the new consent, but I always got in the HttpResponseMessage I got: "StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers" but in the response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() i got: "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken", "message": "Access token validation failure.". Do you thin my token receive in the AuthenticationResult after AcquireTokenAsync can be not suitable for Graph?

Comment: Can you share the contents of your access token using a decoder [like this](http://shawntabrizi.com/jwt/)? Make sure to remove any sensitive data.

Comment: According to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230389/obtaining-a-valid-access-token-for-microsoft-graph-api  We can't use ADAL token for quering the Microsoft Graph. They sais to use graph.windows.net. But I think Microsoft do no recommend that...

Comment: what do you need. The header and the first part of the Payload?

Comment: I do not need the header, just the body. Please edit into your main post. Also the post you linked to is inaccurate. You absolutely can get an access token to the Microsoft Graph using ADAL. Try it with my PowerShell scripts [here](http://shawntabrizi.com/aad/azure-ad-authentication-with-powershell-and-adal/).

Comment: Done, tell me if I mask to much needed information.

Comment: The problem here is you are getting an access token for the wrong API. Note the `aud` claim in your token is "93f...". It should be `https://graph.microsoft.com` or `00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000`. See [here](http://shawntabrizi.com/aad/common-microsoft-resources-azure-active-directory/). Check your authentication code is targeting the right resource.